# CSS: So... opacity attribute is not working in Internet Explorer right?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm using `opacity:0.4` property on a `<div>` element in my page.

I've just realised now that it doesn't work in IE at all... the color of the background is completely opaque.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this set:

```
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity:0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
```

Not pretty, but it's cross-browser.  IE uses the `filter`.

Comment: @Patrik: I think nowdays you can skip "-moz-opacity" and "-ktml-opacity" are for very old browsers http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

Answer (score 2):

IE doesn't support opacity. You can use MS's alpha filter instead:

```
filter:alpha(opacity=40);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532967%28VS.85%29.aspx